# AngularJS/Material - Simple select-Field not working on ios-devices

Tags: ios, angularjs, select, angular-material

I've a strange behaviour with a simple  field when using AngularJS (1.8.2) and Angular material (1.2.2).

The whole thing seems to only affect current IOS devices. I've testet the issue with an iPhone11 and an iPhone12, both with IOS 14.5.

As soon as angular material is loaded, the select field no longer works as usual.
Sometimes the selection works, sometimes not.

Does anyone have an idea what this could be? Did I miss something?

https://codepen.io/pseiferth/pen/rNyeoaj

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngMaterial']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.value = '2';
  
  $scope.changed = function(event) {
    console.log("value changed", $scope.value, event);
  } 
});
```

HTML:

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<h1>
    Test: {{value}}
</h1>
<div>
    <select ng-model="value" ng-change="changed($event)">
        <option ng-value="undefined"> --Select-- </option>
        <option value="1">Value 1</option>
        <option value="2">Value 2</option>
        <option value="3">Value 3</option>
        <option value="4">Value 4</option>
    </select>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've fixed the issue.

It is due to hijacking detection of Angular material.
If this is disabled for mobile devices, the select field works fine.

You can find more information here:
https://material.angularjs.org/1.1.9/api/service/$mdGestureProvider